# Query about Spring Transaction configuration and propagation

Tags: java, spring, transactions

IN spring docs it's written

> The most important concepts to grasp with regard to the Spring Framework's declarative transaction
>   support are that this support is enabled via AOP proxies, and that the transactional advice is driven by
>   metadata (currently XML- or annotation-based).

So If i use

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" order="100"/>
```

in config file and not use `@Transactional` annotation on my beans. Would transaction still be supported, as I am using AOP and transaction Interceptor should be built-in to my AOPs thus no use of explicitly using `@Transactional` annotation.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not using @Transactional annotation and still things seem to work, I wanted to know how it happens under-the-hood

Comment: If you don't explicitly denote transaction boundaries, "things will work". Each database operation will be committed upon completion.

Answer (score 3):

No, you'd still have to use the `@Transactional` annotation. AOP proxy is only used to inject the transaction related code into your code.

Comment: I am not using @Transactional annotation and still things seem to work, I wanted to know how it happens under-the-hood

Comment: @TarunSapra see my answer below .

Answer (score 1):

1. < tx:annotation-driven /> is used to auto detect the '@Transactional' annotation .So it's necessary to have one . Reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).
2. The proxy-target-class="true" decides whether Spring should use JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB class based proxies . See the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) for more info . Basically if your class implements atleast one interface, JDK dynamic proxies are used . If you have a class MyDaoImpl extends MyDao and in your service , you inject the dao reference via MyDaoImpl myDaoImpl , JDK dynamic proxies will not work if the annotations are on your interface as class bases proxies are created with proxy-target-class="true"  and @Transactional annotation is not inherited .
3. The reason why your queries seem to work without @Transactional may be because you are using hibernate template which opens and closes the transactions internally . From Spring 3 , it is recommended to inject sessionFactory directly and not to use hibernate template .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am using SQLMapClientTemplate of iBatis.